# Can we start clan war league without our clan leader?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Can we start clan war league without our clan leader? He has stopped playing the game.

Answer (score 5):

You can! From the [wiki page on Clan Wars](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ):

> Leaders and **co-leaders** can take their clan to war by opening the clan
>   war screen and pressing the “Start War” button.

As long as your clan has an active co-leader, you can still participate in clan wars.

Answer (score 1):

I can enroll my clan into the Clan War **League** (which is completely separate from Clan Wars) as a Co-Leader during the opt-in period. I can also choose which clan members are in/out of the CWL, and change participants each war.